# Simplifying MongoDB aggregation $project stage

Tags: mongodb, conditional-statements, aggregation-framework

I have the following working `$project` stage in my MongoDB aggregation pipeline. The issue is that I am not fully happy with it and would like to hear your suggestions on how the stage could be improved:

```
$project: {
    _id: 0,
    name: 1,
    points: 1,
    level: {
        $cond: {
            if: { $gt: [ "$points", 250 ] },
            then: {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $gt: [ "$points", 500 ] },
                    then: {
                        $cond: {
                            if: { $gt: [ "$points", 3000 ] },
                            then: {
                                $cond: {
                                    if: { $gt: [ "$points", 5000 ] },
                                    then: {
                                        $cond: {
                                            if: { $gt: [ "$points", 20000 ] },
                                            then: 6,
                                            else: 5
                                        }
                                    },
                                    else: 4
                                }
                            },
                            else: 3
                        }
                    },
                    else: 2
                }
            },
            else: 1
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, what the project stage does is compute a certain `level` (1-6), based on achieved `points`. Right now it looks really hard to read and error prone, any suggestions on how to improve would be welcome.

Comment: One option is to use `$switch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [`$switch`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      points: 1,
      level: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {$lte: ["$points", 250]},
              then: 1
            },
            {
              case: {$and: [{$gt: ["$points", 250]}, {$lt: ["$points", 500]}]}, 
              then: 2
            },
            {
              case: {$and: [{$gt: ["$points", 500]}, {$lt: ["$points", 3000]}]}, 
              then: 3
            },
          ],
          default: 4
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e3MjO8I9kGN), although it looks like [repeating the lower bound is redundent](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rpn_m5ptt64).

Comment: This already looks much better, thank you! Do you have any idea if $switch or $cond is better for performance?

Comment: I don't know if it has better performance, just that it is considered as the way to go in such cases